# Closing around a variable in an event handler

Tags: javascript, event-handling, closures

I know there is a smart way to utilize closures and do what I am looking for, but I'm not sure what it is.

In the following code:

```
var MyApp = {
  innerObject : {
    myData : "test value",
    myMethod : function() {
      // 'this' ends up referring to HTMLElement, not what I want 
      alert(this.myData);
    }
  }
  open : function() {
    document.getElementById('connectLink').addEventListener('click', this.innerObject.myMethod, false);
  }
}
MyApp.open();
```

I am looking to attach an event handler to the element with id = 'connectLink' to a method inside innerObject. That method accesses other data inside innerObject to carry out its function. I know this has something to do with the tricky nature of the keyword `this` in javascript. Is there a pattern I can adopt to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a reference to `this` and pass an anonymous function:

```
var self = this;
document.getElementById('connectLink').addEventListener('click', function() {
    self.innerObject.myMethod();
}, false);
```

Also remember that you have to use `attachEvent` in IE.

**Update:**

Newer browsers provide [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which lets you bind the context of the function to a certain object. This is probably the cleanest solution. The link above provides an implementation for browsers that don't support it.

```
el.addEventListener(
    'click', 
    this.innerObject.myMethod.bind(this.innerObject), 
    false
);
```

Comment: Just for clarify that's < IE9 for `attachEvent()`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that by convention, identifiers starting with a capital letter represent constructors.

Remeber that `this` is set by the call, not by the declaration or initialisation (except for ES 5 *bind*, which isn't ready for use on the general web yet).

You can do:

```
myMethod : function() {
      alert(MyApp.innerObject.myData);
}
```

Or you can create *MyApp* using the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) to keep a reference to *innerObject* (there are [some who think it's overused](http://edspencer.net/2009/10/javascript-module-pattern-overused-dangerous-and-bloody-annoying.html)). But even so, `this` within the listener will reference the element it is set on.

Comment: would adopting the module pattern actually help solve the problem of referencing myData inside the handler? if so, i would really like to do that. Felix's answer sounds like it would work, but it makes my code much less readable. how would you structure this functionality using the module pattern?

Comment: The function assigned as the **listener** can have a closure to *MyApp.innerObject* and reference it as <identifer>.property. Felix's answer suggests a closure but doesn't really help with implementation. In any case, I'd use use the fully qualified reference — it's obvious what it references to it's simpler and easier to maintain.